# Эффективный способ выбрать максимум

Tags: sql, oracle, запрос, oracle12c

Как можно наиболее эффективно выбрать максимальное значение. Пока созрело 3 варианта:

1 - Классика

```
select max(log_id) from log where param = 16
```

2 - Извращения

```
select log_id from log where param = 16 order by log_id desc nulls last fetch next 1 rows only
```

3 - Аналитика

```
select v from
(
    select max(log_id) over () v from log where param = 16 
)
where rownum = 1
```

Судя по планам запросов в моей среде БД самый эффективный - последний. Может есть варианты еще более эффективные?

Comment: неплохо было бы приложить планы выполнения

Comment: У меня нет оракла, но не поверю что третий вариант самый эффективный, потому как аналитические запросы выполняются над результатами выборки. Т.е. условие where возвращает множество записей, затем к ним применяется аналитический запрос. Конечно оптимизатор оракла мощный но может быть ты не правильно толкуешь квери план? Не стоит оценивать скорость запроса по "попугаям", полученные цифры от разных запросов не соотносимы. Я думаю самым быстрым должен быть первый запрос.

Answer (score 5):

А вы уверены, что это является узким местом в вашей БД?

Или вы пытаетесь выполнить преждевременную оптимизацию до появления самой проблемы?

> Преждевременная оптимизация-корень всех бед

Имхо, первый вариант с учетом того, что существует индекс по `param` должен отрабатывать моментально. На сколько я знаю, то индекс по полю по которому считается MAX тоже должен ускорить выборку, так как данные будут заранее отсортированы.

+БД должна кешировать данные=> повторное выполнение запроса с другими параметрами должно отработать еще быстрее за счет того, что все данные были ранее вычитаны и загружены в ОЗУ.

Если разница между этими 3 решениями и есть, то это какие-то считанные мс, которые не стоят уродства кода.

Comment: Интересует, скорее, теоретически, чтобы понимать какие подходы можно использовать когда это станет узким местом ))

Comment: Вот когда станет, тогда и отпрофилируете, и проанализируете, и оптимизируете. А сейчас это все пустое.

Answer (score 3):

Если у вас может быть более одной записи с `param = 16`, то 3-й вариант может вернуть неправильный результат, потому что предикат `rownum = 1` отработает до `max(log_id)`.

Поэтому я бы выбрал 1-й вариант.

Comment: Забыл про очередь обработки where, спасибо. Внес исправления.